# How to put those content into the variable one by one and then output it?

Tags: php, arrays

Supposed a text file named `name.txt`. there are some contents as the following in it:

```
Michal Guiles,Tanika Mcall,Jerry Sanipasi,Fallon Mcgillivray,Kurtis Bouras,Maria Teschner,Jerry Barbot,Earnestine
```

how to put all the names into a variable named `$name`; then output them one by one by `$comment->setname("$name");`

Comment: have you thought of reading your file line by line, splitting them along `,` storing them in an array and iterating them in a `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Read the file :**

```
$file_handle = fopen("myfile.text", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

**Split the parts :**

```
$parts = explode(",",$line);
```

**Print them one by one :**

```
foreach ($parts as $part)
{
    echo "$part<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're asking about multiple things at once. Just do one thing after the other:

1. Read the file: (see [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents))

   ```
   $text = file_get_contents('name.txt');
   ```
2. Retrieve the names: (see [`explode`](http://php.net/explode))

   ```
   $names = explode(',', $text);
   ```
3. Iterate over the names: (see [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach))

   ```
   foreach ($names as $name)
   {
       $comment->setname($name);
   }
   ```